# Model performance metric on the test sample

Tags: model-evaluation, uncertainty, metric, generalization-error

Since usually k-fold cross validation is carried out on the training sample I understand how the mean and the standard deviation of a metric are computed for the training sample but how is the mean computed on the test sample?

Once the model is selected after the cross validation procedure it is used to score the test sample and only a single number is generated for a given metric (e.g. accuracy). There is nested cross-validation technique that gives multiple test sets and thus one can compute the mean of a metric for the test set but I don't think everyone reporting the mean metric on the test set is using that method. Another option is bootstrapping: some papers say they resample test data multiple times. But once the dataset is splitted into training and test sets the latter is fixed. So "resampling the test set" is not clear to me.